# Ubuntu 13.04 Upload Speed Slow

Tags: networking, ethernet, lan

I have 2 machines on the same LAN. One downloads and uploads perfectly. The other downloads great, but the upload is painfully slow ~30kb/s. It's using the onboard ethernet port, which I think is a gigabit port. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would firstly try changing the cable to the slow computer it could be a dry joint.

Next I'd check that all connections are pushed home fully in the server and at the PC ends. It may do nothing, but it is better than finding out after doing something that may take a lot longer!

Comment: I don't think that's the case since I plugged the cord into a 3rd machine and it connects and uploads fine.